# How to upgrade botocore1.2.6 to 1.4 or above present with boto3?

Tags: python, boto3, botocore

I have boto3 installed on my linux machine. When I pass below command, I get botocore version as 1.2.6

```
>>> import boto3
>>> print boto3.__version__
1.2.6
```

How to upgrade to botocore present within boto3 to 1.4 or latest version? In case I need to downgrade botocore 1.4 to botocore 1.2.6 , what are the steps ?

Comment: How did you install boto3 in the first place?

Answer (score 30):

If you use [PIP](https://packaging.python.org/installing/)

```
# upgrade
pip install botocore --upgrade
pip install boto3 --upgrade

# Specify version 
pip install botocore==1.2.6
```

(update)

As mentioend by @Kyle Bridenstine , you may need specify Pip version for python3.

IMHO, all python project should load under [a python virtualenvironment](https://towardsdatascience.com/comparing-python-virtual-environment-tools-9a6543643a44), not matter it is under development, staging or production. This extra work will save your hassle to deal with explicit version requirement .

Comment: On AWS EC2 I'm using Python 3.6 so I use Pip-3.6 instead of just Pip so the commands for me are `pip-3.6 install botocore --upgrade` and `pip-3.6 install boto3 --upgrade`. Depending on your version it would change to like `pip-3.5 install botocore --upgrade` and `pip-3.5 install boto3 --upgrade` or `pip-2.7 install botocore --upgrade` and `pip-2.7 install boto3 --upgrade`.

Comment: @KyleBridenstine : For python , always deploy python virtual environment even for production, this will solve most of the version conflict.